# Why do I get 401 Unauthorized when granting access via Azure AD App-Only?

Tags: c#, winforms, azure-active-directory, pnp-framework

I followed this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) but I modified the sample code a bit to use `GetContextAsync` instead of `GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext`, I get the error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." every single time.

```cs
AuthenticationManager authManager = new AuthenticationManager(clientId, certPath,certPassword,tenantId);
using (ClientContext cc = await authManager.GetContextAsync(_siteUrl))
{
    cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
    await cc.ExecuteQueryAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);
}
```

The error is thrown at `await cc.ExecuteQueryAsync();`
I have uploaded the self-signed certificate onto Azure portal
[image: cert]

and granted the permission
[image: granted]

My app is a Winforms app using .NET framework 4.7
PnP.Framework 1.11

P/s: What do I enter for the `tenantId` param? At the moment I'm using the Directory (tenant) ID from the Overview page [image: tenant]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the same in my environment.

- Created self signed certificate

[image]

It is then being uploaded to my app registration

[image]

Checked the manifest to confirm

[image]

```
"keyCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": "xxx",
            "endDate": "2023-01-31T00:00:00Z",
            "keyId": "xxx",
            "startDate": "2023-01-23T00:00:00Z",
            "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
            "usage": "Verify",
            "value": "xxx",
            "displayName": "my new ssc"
        }
```

using postman

[image]

code given:

```
using System;
using PnP.Framework;
//using OfficeDevPnP.Core;
//using Microsoft.SharePoint;
//using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
namespace spoapprepo
{
    class Program
    {
        static async void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientId = "xxx";
            var certPath = "C:\\xxx\\selfsigned.pfx";
            var certPassword = "xxx";
            var tenantId = "xxx";
            var siteUrl= "https://contoso.sharepoint.com";


            AuthenticationManager authManager = new AuthenticationManager(clientId, certPath, certPassword, tenantId);
Try{
            using (var cc = await authManager.GetContextAsync(siteUrl))
            {
                cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
                await cc.ExecuteQueryAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);
            }



            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
}
catch(ex)
{
Ex.message();
}
```

Try using `if-else` and `try-catch` block to catch the exact error.

As `getcontext` uses current users credentials , but here we are intended to use app only context.

If users login is not having privileges to access the sharepoint or when entered wrong Login details , the 401 unauthorized usually occurs.

[image]

If the user profile needs to be read , it needs `user.read` permission.

[image]

But ***note the limitation*** [Accessing SharePoint using an application context, also known as app-only | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly?source=recommendations#what-are-the-limitations-when-using-app-only) here.

> ***User Profile CSOM write operations do not work with Azure AD application  Only read operations work.***
>
> ***For writing you need to user to login, use SharePoint App-Only principal***

**Reference :** [azure active directory - SharePoint PnP AuthenticationManager login with current user - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919974/sharepoint-pnp-authenticationmanager-login-with-current-user)

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the 401 error using the Azure AD app-only method like I did? Your answer wasn't very clear. With regards to the user profile permission, I have already added the User.Read permission. The intended outcome of my app is to read and write on SP document libraries, not user profile.